# how to extract $children$html contents from an XMLDocumentContent object

Tags: html, xml, r

apologies in advance, i am sure this is simple but i cannot figure out what i'm doing wrong..

in addition to other things, this code..

```
study.name <- 'NLSY79'
library(XML)
library(httr)
sub.study <- paste0( "https://www.nlsinfo.org/investigator/servlet1?get=SUBSTUDIES&study=" , study.name )
study.html <- GET( sub.study )
content( study.html )
study.block <- htmlParse( study.html , asText = TRUE )
```

..gives me..

```
$children$html
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   false
   <select id="thesubstudies" onchange="onSubstudyChanged(this);">
    <option value="-1" selected="selected">(Choose One)</option>
    <option value="343.06">NLSY79 (1979-2010)</option>
   </select>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

i just want a quick (automatic) way to extract the "343.06"

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xpathSApply` to extract the elements you want

```
xpathSApply(study.block, "//option")
# [[1]]
# <option value="-1" selected="selected">(Choose One)</option> 
# [[2]]
# <option value="343.06">NLSY79 (1979-2010)</option>
```

and apply a function on them (`xmlValue` or `xmlAttrs`, depending on the context).

```
xpathSApply(study.block, "//option", function(u) xmlAttrs(u)["value"])
#   value    value 
#    "-1" "343.06"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `xmlGetAtrr`

```
xpathSApply(study.block, "//option", xmlGetAttr, "value")
[1] "-1"     "343.06"
```

or

```
xpathSApply(study.block, "//option[not(@selected)]", xmlGetAttr, "value")
[1] "343.06"
```